# Lightning Component Tutorial ExpenseTracker load Javascript error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I tried Lightning component tutorial on creating expenseTracker.app.When the page load, in Java console it return this error.
[image]

Why?Anyone face this error?
I click on the top error and here the snippet of error.

GET https://unid-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/fonts/proximanovasoft-regular.woff ltng$require.Helper.inject @ app.js:3869$A.clientService.initDefs.componentDefs.v.controllerDef.v.actionDefs.v.code @ app.js:14590Action.$runDeprecated$ @ aura_proddebug.js:5489Component$getActionCaller @ aura_proddebug.js:3598(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:5061$A.$ns$.$Aura$.$run$ @ aura_proddebug.js:11027Event.$fire$ @ aura_proddebug.js:5036Component.$fire$ @ aura_proddebug.js:4517Component @ aura_proddebug.js:3976aura$component @ app.js:7ltng$require @ app.js:3839$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$createComponentInstance$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8160$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$newComponentDeprecated$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8117ComponentPriv$$0.$createComponentStack$ @ aura_proddebug.js:3373ComponentPriv$$0.$setupAttributes$ @ aura_proddebug.js:3465ComponentPriv @ aura_proddebug.js:3260Component @ aura_proddebug.js:3973aura$component @ app.js:7aura$application @ app.js:4319$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$createComponentInstance$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8160$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$newComponentDeprecated$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8117ComponentPriv$$0.$setupSuper$ @ aura_proddebug.js:3408ComponentPriv @ aura_proddebug.js:3266Component @ aura_proddebug.js:3973aura$component @ app.js:7aura$application @ app.js:4319unid$expenseTracker @ app.js:4472$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$createComponentInstance$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8160$A.$ns$.$AuraComponentService$.$newComponentDeprecated$ @ aura_proddebug.js:8117$A.$ns$.$AuraClientService$.$init$ @ aura_proddebug.js:7541MetricsService.$instrument$.instance.(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:10523$A.$ns$.$Aura$.$initPriv$ @ aura_proddebug.js:10927(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:10906(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:7614ServerActionsMetricsPlugin.bind.actionHook @ aura_proddebug.js:11654Action.$finishAction$ @ aura_proddebug.js:5611(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:7153$A.$ns$.$Aura$.$run$ @ aura_proddebug.js:11027$A.$ns$.$AuraClientService$.$singleAction$ @ aura_proddebug.js:7145$A.$ns$.$AuraClientService$.$doActionCallback$ @ aura_proddebug.js:7236(anonymous function) @ aura_proddebug.js:7193$A.$ns$.$Aura$.$run$ @ aura_proddebug.js:11027$A.$ns$.$AuraClientService$.$actionCallback$ @ aura_proddebug.js:7192$A.$ns$.$AuraClientService$.$finishRequest$.requestConfig.callback @ aura_proddebug.js:7294TransportMetricsPlugin.bind.config.callback @ aura_proddebug.js:11593Transport.$request$.request.onreadystatechange @ aura_proddebug.js:1869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font **Proxima Nova** is a proprietary font and is not included with salesforce foundation bootstrap sf1 css file. Only Glyph-icons font is bundled.

Actually this error does not imposes any functional issue, it's just that your browser is not able to locate the font at a specified location and will try to use different font (Calibri).

Still, If you want to remove the error, open you file with a text editor (I used Notepad++)In you CSS file, you will find references to proxima font. (In bootstrap-namespaced, I found it at line 6299)

**Example**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaSoft-Regular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaSoft-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaSoft-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNovaSoft-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ProximaNovaSoft-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNovaSoft-Regular.svg#proxima_nova_softregular') format('svg');
}
```

Delete those blocks.

**Optional:**

Search for name `font-family: "ProximaNovaSoft-Regular"` and replace it with font name of your choice.

Then you can upload the file back in your static resource and use it.